# Display entries tagged with specific tag(s) before other entries

Tags: entries, tags, ordering

What I'm trying to accomplish is looping through a collection of entries and have them display (*with pagination*) in the following order:

- entries tagged as **Featured** in alphabetical (title) order
- entries tagged as **New** in alphabetical (title) order
- all remaining entries in alphabetical (title) order

The following worked:

```
craft.entries({ order: 'featuredLightswitchField desc, title asc' })
```

However it fails to work if you try to use two lightswitch fields (e.g. featured and new) in addition to the title ordering, and I'd prefer to keep things tag-based instead of needing to add lightswitch fields.

I also attempted at creating a custom array of entry IDs in the proper order and passing it to `craft.entries.id()`, however I can't find a way of keeping the entries in the order of the array passed to `craft.entries.id()`.

```
craft.entries({ id: [3, 1, 2] })
// can't find a way to keep entries in [3, 1, 2] order.
```

If there was a way to order the entries based off the `id` array that would solve the problem, unless there's a better solution.

Can provide additional information if my explanation is insufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track with merging arrays of entry IDs. And to keep the sort order with your new `craft.entries` call there's in fact a method for that: [`fixedOrder(true)`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries).

Comment: Not sure how I missed that, exactly what I needed. Thanks!